# How to add multiple youtube playlist with video in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, youtube-data-api

I need to add Youtube playlist with Youtube player in my flutter application.And i want to add multiple playlist. When i will upload video to youtube then autometically will have to appears on my flutter app.

I saw some tutorial, where people use hereku server to fetch youtube api to flutter app. But they use just a single playlist. here is the [link](https://youtu.be/NehGIaUIRx0)

Can you tell me how i can add multiple playlist on my app.
Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could maybe try a combination of this two packages:

[youtube_api](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api):
With this package you could fetch all the videos inside a playlist and (as it goes directly through Youtube API) the list should update as soon as a new video is uploaded.

[youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter):
Given a certain list of youtube video ids, you can use this player to reproduce them (I’ve used it in a project and worked perfectly, even with live streams)

So, I guess that combining them would be my fist approach.

**Update 31 Jan 20201**

I tried [youtube_api](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api) package but couldn't make it load the videos from a specific youtube playlistId neither, so I've checked their code and created a new implementation that only retrieves the videos from a specific playlistId.

Here is the code if you want to take a look https://github.com/rodrigoc85/flutter-load-youtube-playlist

Comment: Thanks. I will try them.

Comment: youtube api package don't let me search using exact playlist link. How to I add exact playlist with this youtube api package ??

Comment: Take a look at the update on my original answer. I couldn't make it work with youtube_api package, but there you have a sample of how to do it. Remember to add your own api key before running.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts 